# Как присвоить переменной определенному месту в предложении?

Tags: c#

Создавал приложение, и нужно было сделать функцию - при вводе слов: 
"создать (какой блокнот нужно создать? )  блокнот" должна создаваться переменная со значением второго слова в этом предложении. Но получается это сделать только массивом. Возможно ли это решить без массива? Т.к. будет вообще неудобно, много чего переписывать понадобится. Вот пример кода:

```
String[] wordsArray = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (wordsArray[0] == "Создать" && wordsArray[2] == "блокнот")
{
    string a = wordsArray[1];
    Console.WriteLine("Была создана переменная: " + a);
}
```

P.S. Желательно пример с тремя и более словами

Comment: В принципе всё верно. Только объявление переменной `a` нужно вынести из блока `if`. Тогда к ней можно будет обращаться не только в этом блоке.

Comment: если я правильно понял каждый раз вводится одна и та же сообщение?то есть  "создать (какой блокнот нужно создать? ) блокнот".Так или нет?

Comment: @VardanVardanyan Ну создать, и что создать: кнопку например или блокнот, что угодно

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Можно пример кода?

Answer (score 1):

Для трех и более слов можно написать так, используя класс `StringBuilder`:

```
    string words = Console.ReadLine();

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Помещаем в sb первое слово
    int i = 0;
    while (i < words.Length && words[i] != ' ')
        sb.Append(words[i++]);

    if (sb.ToString() != "Создать") return;

    int startIndex = i + 1;

    // Помещаем в sb второе слово
    i = words.Length - 1;
    sb.Clear();

    while (words[i] != ' ')
        i--;

    int endIndex = i - 1;

    i++;
    while (i < words.Length)
        sb.Append(words[i++]);

    if (sb.ToString() != "блокнот") return;

    sb.Clear();

    // Помещаем в sb все, что находится между первым и вторым словом
    for (i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
        sb.Append(words[i]);

    string a = sb.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Была создана переменная: " + a);
```

Comment: Что-то муть какая-то...

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=создать\s)(.*)(?=\sблокнот)");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var result = regex.Match(input).Value?.Trim();
```

Comment: Кстати, для такого задания регулярные выражения - самый подходящий способ. Только мне кажется, что между словами `cоздать` и `блокнот` должно быть хотя бы 2 пробела (потому что то, что стоит между ними, отделяется пробелами от крайних слов), поэтому поправьте регулярку. +1 с меня

Comment: согласен, для таких достаточно простых случаев самое то что надо

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял вопрос, автору нужно переменную со введённым значением использовать дальше по коду.

```
if (...)
{
    // Здесь a - локальная переменная.
    // Она видна только в пределах блока, ограниченного скобками { }
    string a = wordsArray[1];
    ...
}
// За скобками эта переменная уже не видна
Console.WriteLine(a); // ошибка - нет такой переменной
```

Чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно вынести объявление переменной за пределы блока.

```
// Объявление переменной
string a = null;

if (...)
{
    // Присваивание переменной.
    // Обратите внимание, перед ней нет string.
    a = wordsArray[1];
    ...
}

Console.WriteLine(a); // работает
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял то можно написать такой код

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
var a = str!=null ? str.Split(' ')[1] : "переменная не создана";
Console.WriteLine("Была создана переменная:{0}",a);
```

Comment: IndexOutOfBounds